# unsetting jquery cookie with php

Tags: php, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've done

```
<?php 
echo "initial values in the cart: <pre>";print_r($_COOKIE);echo "</pre>"; 
  $_COOKIE['cart']=null;
  setcookie("cart", "", time()-3600);  
 unset($_COOKIE['cart']); 
 unset($_COOKIE); 

 ?>
 <script>
 alert( "before delete         " +$.cookie("cart") ); 
 </script>  

   <script>
      $.cookie("cart")="";
      $.cookie('cart', null);
      $.cookie('cart',null,{path:'/');
     $.cookie("cart")=null;
     $.cookie('cart', '', { expires: -150 });
     jQuery.cookie("cart", '',{expires: -1,path:'/'});
     $.cookie("cart")=undefined;
     delete $.cookie("cart");
     $.cookie("cart","",); 
     $.removeCookie('cart', { path: '/' });  
     $.removeCookie("cart"); 
     alert( "just delete         " +$.cookie("cart") );
 </script> 
 <script>
 if($.cookie('cart') === null || $.cookie('cart') === "")
{ 
      alert( " cookie deleted 1         " +$.cookie("cart") );
}

else
{
     //have cookie
     alert( "have cookie         " +$.cookie("cart") );
} 

if (typeof $.cookie('cart') === 'undefined'){
 //no cookie
 alert( " cookie deleted 2        " +$.cookie("cart") );
}
 // if($.cookie('cart') === null || $.cookie('cart') === "" 
    // || $.(cookie('cart') === "null" || $.cookie('cart') === undefined))
// {
      // alert( " cart cookie deleted 3        " +$.cookie("cart") );
// }
</script>

  <script>
 alert( "after delete         " + $.cookie("cart") ); 
 </script>  
  <?php
  echo "Items after cookie in the cart is unset: <pre>";print_r($_COOKIE);echo "</pre>";  
  ?>
```

output is: 
(1) it prints the initial values in the cart, cookie has cart variable set 
(2) before delete alert 
(3) have cookie alert 
(4) after delete alert 
(5) `print_r` throwing notice `Undefined variable: _COOKIE`

Insights: 
--> primarily am setting cookie through jquery and am able to access it by output (1) 
--> next i `unset` cookie `print_r` throwing says `Undefined variable` and with through alerts am still able to see the cookie value, I tried to delete the cookie in the jquery way yet in all alerts cookie value is shown, in the end again `print_r($_COOKIE)` says `Undefined variable` 
--> i wish on page refresh output (1) i.e., `print_($_COOKIE['cart'])` has to say `Undefined variable cart` but still returning original/old cookie-cart variable.

please suggest me how to unset the cookie properly 

 with mozilla's cookie add-on i found path of cookie is correct as mentioned above 

**solved**
leaving jquery aside i tried `setcookie('cart', null, -1, '/');` and it has solved my issue! 
Thanks!

Comment: You can't force the browser to delete the cookie file. You can, however, delete the contents of the cookie and expire it

Comment: your question may be dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252394/php-cant-remove-cookie-that-was-set-by-javascript

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I tried to unset & delete cookie variable with php & jquery but i failed to achieve the same! thanks for the reference but i found no solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Things to consider:**

1. Don't touch variables in [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) global. It will not change the actual cookie.
2. Javascript changes cookies live, for php you might need to refresh the page. It depends on how your script is built. `Example:` setting a cookie in php and change it in php, requires a refresh.
3. Cookies have domain and path. You have set the path to `/` and domain to `domain.com`, that's exactly what you need to send in order to delete the cookie. Example:

setting a cookie:

```
setcookie("cart", "my content", time()+3600, "/", "domain.com");
```

unsetting the cookie:

```
setcookie("cart", "", time()-3600, "/", "domain.com");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just solved it with ref from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19972329/1528701

Comment: Just don't `unset($_COOKIE['Hello']);` as that guy did, it's pointless to do it.